# Regex replace where an occurence count is reused in the replacing pattern

Tags: .net, regex

I want to find and remove blank lines before closing curly brackets like in the following snippet after the property `Bar`:

```
namespace Baz
{
  class Foo
  {
    public int Bar { get; }

  }
}
```

The regex to match the location is `\n\n\t*}` since the given source code contains tab characters. What is the replace pattern so that the result of the replacement is that the blank line is removed? Is there a simpler way to achieve it?

Note that I cannot replace the occurance simply with `}` because the indentation of it must remain unchanged - in this case one tab character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you would want a single newline removed so you need to capture from the input, excluding a single newline: `\n(\n\t*})` and return that group in the output `\1` or `$1` for .NET.

Here it is working on your example at [regex 101](https://regex101.com/r/ycZ5mj/2).

Comment: I think the replacement should be `$1`, it is for .NET.

Comment: Great, that is really elegant and simple. I ended up with this line of C# code: `return new Regex(@"\r\n(\r\n\t*})").Replace(input, "$1")`